# Flickr: Same photo multiple permissions

Tags: flickr

- Lets say I upload 10 images on Flickr
- I put all the 10 images in set1 with private permissions(visible only to me and my friends and family)

Now, lets say out of these 10 photos, I want to share 4 photos to everyone (public). So, can I do it by creating another set, set2, and by putting set2 permissions as public? I tried doing it however it does not work?

How can I achieve my goal? Are the permissions tied to a photo or to a set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions are tied to a photo. Unless I'm misunderstanding things, you should be able to accomplish what you want simply by marking the four photos you want other people to be able to see as public. For example, [this set of mine](http://www.flickr.com/photos/pak21/sets/72157637357537055/) actually has 17 photos in it - but you can see only 5 of them; the other 12 are private.

Comment: Not a problem :-) If you press the little tick under the voting buttons, you can mark whichever answer to a question you think is the most useful as "accepted" so that future visitors to a question can see that information quickly. In this case, it's a bit trivial right now, but it's still a good thing to do - and you'll get a small amount of reputation for doing so. Disclaimer: I'll also get a larger amount of reputation for doing this.